# Como hacer un grafico horizontal sobre determinadas columnas de una tabla?

Tags: html, table

Tengo que hacer este grafico en html, donde el valor que tiene la columna "NIVEL" sera el tamaño del grafico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para simular el grafico, lo intenté pintando un  dentro de cada celda, pero se ven los bordes de las columnas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien tiene una idea de como poder realizar el grafico y que se vea como en la primera imagen?
Muchas gracias.

Parte del codigo de la tabla lo tengo así:

```
 <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2"><strong>NIVEL</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><div class="graficoAmarillo"></div></td>
            <td><div class="graficoAmarillo"></div></td>
            <td><div class="graficoAmarillo"></div></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Dado que la pregunta es de como pintarlo y has puesto el HTML, es necesario, que pongas el código CSS asociado a dicha pregunta.

Comment: Este problema se resuelve en el CSS. Una ayuda podría ser poniendo las celdas `td` coloreadas con `border:none;` y luego `background:yellow;`

Comment: ¿Realmente necesitas una tabla para esto? Parece más un gráfico que una tabla con datos.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr algo similar a la imagen, utilizando tablas, vas necesitar utilizar muchas propiedades `CSS` que quizas no conozcas:

- [border-collpase](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse): para que los bordes de las celdas y la tabla no se dupliquen
- [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing): para que las celdas midan exactamente lo que establecemos en su width
- [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/calc()): para hacer cálculos matemáticos y los elementos midan exactamente lo que necesitamos
- [translate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()): en este caso, para centrar el elemento verticalmente
- [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow): para crear sobras sobre un elemento.

Empleando las propiedades `CSS` anteriores y otras más, podemos lograr lo siguiente:

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.table td {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px dashed #000;
}
.table-header,
.table-subheader {
  border: 2px solid #000 !important;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
}
.table-subheader {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
.table-height-3 {
  height: 150px;
}

.table-bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100px - (6px * 2)); /* cell-width - (bar-margin x 2) */
  margin-left: calc(6px - 2px); /* bar-margin - cell-border-width */
  height: 40px;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
}

.table-bar-yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.table-bar-w3 {
  width: calc((100px * 3) - (6px * 2)); /* (cell-width x 3) - (bar-margin x 2) */
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-header" rowspan="2"><strong>NIVEL</strong></td>
      <td class="table-header" colspan="2">Bajo</td>
      <td class="table-header">Medio</td>
      <td class="table-header" colspan="2">Alto</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-subheader">1</td>
      <td class="table-subheader">2</td>
      <td class="table-subheader">3</td>
      <td class="table-subheader">4</td>
      <td class="table-subheader">5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="table-subheader table-height-3">3</td>
      <td>
        <div class="table-bar table-bar-yellow table-bar-w3"></div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes usar los graficos de google
https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/chart

Son bastante sencillos de usar

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>




  google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Titulo', 'Titulo2',],
    ['linea1', 3],
    ['linea2', 1],
    ['linea3', 5],
    ['linea4', 2]
  ]);

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    chartArea: {width: '100%'},
    hAxis: {
        baselineColor: 'transparent',
       textPosition: 'none',
       gridlines: {count: 0}
    },
    vAxis: {
   
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

de este modo obtienes las barras con fondo trasparente que puedes decorar como necesitas al rededor del chart_div

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/378871)